# How to save score without using database ( gambit game with javascript )

Tags: javascript

Today, i start my very first game application with javascripp for studing purpuse. It's a gambit game that you set the bet, chose Odd or Even then Call. It's just a simply game but i get the problem with sumerize the score.

The idea is: I create a callback function to proceed the data, it took value of odd button and even button then comparing to a random number of a variable, then if the result is win, your money will be raised otherwise it's reduced. Here is my js code:

```
var even = document.getElementById('even')
var odd = document.getElementById('odd')
var call = document.getElementById('submit_btn')
var result = document.getElementById('result')
var score = document.getElementById('capital')
function process(choice,money,capital=1000) {
    console.log(capital)
    call.addEventListener('click',function () {
        let luck = Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
        if (choice == luck) {
            capital += parseInt(money) ;
            result.innerHTML = 'win+ '+money;
        } else {
            capital -= money;
            result.innerHTML = 'lose- '+money;
        }
        score.innerHTML = 'Capital: '+capital
        console.log(capital)
        if(capital<1){
            alert('Game Over')
        }
    })
}

even.addEventListener('click',function () {
    let bet = parseInt(document.getElementById('bets').value)
    if(Number.isInteger(bet) == true){
        process(1,bet)
        console.log(bet)
    }else{
        alert('You must bet first!!!')
    }
})

odd.addEventListener('click',function () {
    let bet = parseInt(document.getElementById('bets').value)
    if(Number.isInteger(bet) == true){
        process(0,bet)
        console.log(bet)
    }else{
        alert('You must bet first!!!')
    }
})
```

[here is my application](https://codepen.io/VanDeco/pen/bXmpvV).

My problem is it works correctly when I just bet and call but when I change the bet option the money will be reset. How could I save the result then use it when another even occur. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi van_deco, welcome to Stack Overflow.  You should post the relevant code here, not just linked to another website.  You don't need all of it, just a minimal amount of game logic.  You can save the "state" of your app in a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

1. In `process(choice,money,capital=1000)` you defined a default value `1000` to `capital`.

   Therefore every time you click `odd` / `even`, it call `process(0,bet) / process(1,bet)`, the capital reset to 1000. Because you didn't provide any value as third parameter.
2. I notice you add event listener in every `process` function, it may cause memory issue. You just need to bind once in this situation.

I will probably write like this:

```
// use IIFE to prevent pollution of global variable
 (function(){
    var even = document.getElementById('even')
    var odd = document.getElementById('odd')
    var call = document.getElementById('submit_btn')
    var result = document.getElementById('result')
    var score = document.getElementById('capital')
    var bet = document.getElementById('bets');

    // define variables here to keep their value.
    var capital = 1000;
    var money = NaN;
    var choice = NaN;
    
    function process(){
      if(Number.isNaN(money) && Number.isNaN(choice)) return;
      
      let luck = Math.floor(Math.random()*2)
      if (choice == luck) {
        capital += parseInt(money) ;
        result.innerHTML = 'win+ '+money;
      } else {
        capital -= money;
        result.innerHTML = 'lose- '+money;
      }
      score.innerHTML = 'Capital: '+capital
      console.log(capital)
      if(capital<1){
        alert('Game Over')
      }
    }

    function chageBet(choice){
       if(Number.isInteger(parseInt(bet.value)) == true){
           choice = choice;
           money = bet.value;
           console.log(bet)
       } else{
            alert('You must bet first!!!')
       }
    }
    // just bind event once
    call.addEventListener('click', process)
    even.addEventListener('click', chageBet.bind(null, 1))
    odd.addEventListener('click', chageBet.bind(null, 0))
})();
```

And maybe it's better to provide a reset function to reset the `capital/money/choice` variables.

Update:
Try to explain how variables change their values.

Round 1
choice is NaN; money is NaN; capital is 1000;

1. User set bet to 10
2. Click even button

   - execute changeBet(1)
   - choice become 1; money become 10;
3. Click call button

   - execute process()
   - (assume)vwin -> capital become 1000 + 10 = 1010

Round 2
choice is 1; money is 10; capital is 1010

1. User set bet to 200
2. Click odd button

   - execute changeBet(0)
   - choice become 0; money become 200;
3. Click call button

   - execute process()
   - lose -> capital become 1010 - 200 = 810

Every click event on button will execute the function that assigned in their addEventListener, and function changes the values of variables.

Please let me know if I am not clear enough.

Comment: Thank you very much, but i don''t understand the code.In the code, how could you bring the data to global like the 'choice' part without calling the function ??? Sorry if i make a stupid question because of my lack of knowledge.

Comment: The function actually is being called in every round.  I updated the answer to explain the process.